# Unable to access parameter defined inside workflow definition template

Tags: parameter-passing, azure-logic-apps

I am setting up the workflow deployment template for a logic app and trying to set up a parameter inside the logic app definition but unable to access it within the logic app.

I have downloaded an existing logic apps into visual studio and created a parameter Get_Profisee_Integrator_output_Path_LA inside logic app (within workflow definition section). I have also set the value for this parameter. When I try to access this parameter inside the logic app, it shows the parameter is undefined.

**Parameter declaration inside workflow deployment template:**

```
"azure_automation_account_ARM": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "BFC-Automation"
    }
```

**Parameter declaration inside workflow definition:**

```
"parameters": {           
            "Get_Profisee_Integrator_output_Path_LA": {
              "defaultValue": "[concat(subscription().id,'/resourceGroups/',resourceGroup().name,'/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/',parameters('azure_automation_account_ARM'),'/jobs/@{encodeURIComponent(body(''Run_Profisee_Integrator_Job'')?[''properties'']?[''jobId''])}/output')]",
              "type": "String"
            }
          }

**Parameter set value:**

          "Get_Profisee_Integrator_output_Path_LA": {
            "value": "[concat(subscription().id,'/resourceGroups/',resourceGroup().name,'/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/',parameters('azure_automation_account_ARM'),'/jobs/@{encodeURIComponent(body(''Run_Profisee_Integrator_Job'')?[''properties'']?[''jobId''])}/output')]"

        }
```

**Accessing the parameter Get_Profisee_Integrator_output_Path_LA inside logic app:**

```
"definition": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
          "actions": {
            "Get_Profisee_Integrator_output": {
              "runAfter": {
                "Run_Profisee_Integrator_Job": [
                  "Succeeded"
                ]
              },
              "type": "ApiConnection",
    "inputs": {
                                "host": {
                                    "connection": {
                                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureautomation']['connectionId']"
                                    }
                                },
                                "method": "get",

                                "path": "[parameters('Get_Profisee_Integrator_output_Path_LA')]",
                                "queries": {
                                    "x-ms-api-version": "2015-10-31"
                                }
                            }
            }
```

I should be able to access the parameter Get_Profisee_Integrator_output_Path_LA to set the path of an action but unable to. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by creating individual parameters for the path parameter and use those to evaluate the path.

```
"path": "/subscriptions/@{encodeURIComponent(parameters('subscription_Id_LA'))}/resourceGroups/@{encodeURIComponent(parameters('resource_Group_Name_LA'))}/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/@{encodeURIComponent(parameters('bfc_Automation_Account_Name_LA'))}/jobs/@{encodeURIComponent(body('Run_Profisee_Integrator_Job')?['properties']?['jobId'])}/output",
```